# XSLT get attribute value from XML

Tags: xml, xslt

There's a section in my XML file that contains the following:

```
<Agent>
<GroupsList>
  <int name="55555(My City IIM)">0</int>
</GroupsList>
<Name>John Smith</Name>
</Agent>
```

**How do I get the value "55555(My City IIM)" from the name attribute in the XSLT file?**

I have tried this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Agent/GroupsList/int">
                <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/> : <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
```

but it's returning **int : 0**

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `<xsl:value-of select="@name"/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value of an attribute, prefix the name of the attribute with an `@` and reference it in a `<xsl:value-of select="@ATTRIBUTE_NAME" />.`

In your code example it would be:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Agent/GroupsList/int">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/> : <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So you get:

`55555(My City IIM) : 0`